# java path setting on windows 8.1

Tags: java

I am trying  to set java path on my windows 8.1, and i installed jdk 8u 64 bit and  in environmental variables under system variables there is no PATH found,so i incuded  new path variable to set path for jdk and jre ,by copying the bin path of jdk C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin and i appended jre path C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40,but it doesnt work when i tried in command prompt by typing "java -version"
and "javac" it says that java is not a internal or external command. and i had a doubt that to run java through command prompt ,do we need any other installations like turbo c
please help me out to set path in my pc,i am a begginer of java

thank you

Comment: Can you please provide the result of echo %PATH% ?

Comment: From your command prompt, type `path` and hit enter, let's see what your path actually is.

Answer (score 0):

This path is wrong -

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40C:\Program F iles
>   (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin

you need a `;` in between the two different paths.

Try adding this instead -

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin;C:\Program F iles
>   (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin

Comment: still its not working sir....  command prompt is showing java is not an internal or external command when am typing javac

Comment: Can you add the path again as comment?

Comment: C:\Users\My Dell>path
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.
0_40\bin

C:\Users\My Dell>

Comment: Updated my answer, you need to point the path to the bin folder inside the jdk .

Answer (score 0):

javac is not part of jre, but part of jdk. So have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin` in the path. As Anand noted, the `;` is missing as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to add the path in the user variables

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66
```

in the `JAVA_HOME` don't add any semicolan (`;`) and

```
path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;.;
```

in the path section end of the line add `;.;` to consider all paths and save. Then try to restart system and open the command prompt and try to check

1. `java -version`
2. `javac`

[JAVA_HOME AND PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vPEJ.png)